# Will Condor through-check baggage onto Lufthansa flights on separate tickets?

Tags: luggage, connecting-flights, lufthansa, frankfurt, condor

My next trip is with Lufthansa to Frankfurt, connecting to a Condor flight to Holguin, Cuba. My outbound journey involves an overnight layout in Frankfurt, while my return trip has a 3 hour connection time in Frankfurt.

Lufthansa and Condor both participate in the Miles & More frequent flyer programme and, according to this item https://onemileatatime.com/lufthansa-condor-takeover/ also have an interline agreement. When making this trip for the first time recently, I assumed that I would not be able to check my luggage through to my final destination because the flights were booked as two separate tickets, and therefore I did not even bother to ask when checking in for my return flight. However, now that I know about the links between the two airlines, I’m wondering if it might be possible.

Question: does anyone know if Condor would through-check baggage in this scenario? Is it even worth asking at the check-in desk?

Comment: I would call them. They might do that. I have managed to get Swiss (a LH company)  to through check on to a TAP flight. But i did call first.

Comment: They definitely do that for a single booking (personal experience). But I'm not sure they can arrange this if you fly on different bookings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question, on my return flight I asked to check my bag through to my final destination, but was told it couldn’t be done.

Comment: I can also confirm this is indeed possible when booking a single ticket.

Comment: @Traveller Weren't you worried by the three-hour connection? It looks like I am going to do a very similar [trip](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/178278/three-hour-connection-in-frankfurt).

Comment: Yes, a little, but my experience over the years has been that generally these flights land early. I also often book Premium (means you de-plane faster, and luggage arrives quicker). You can check-in online, bag drop is pretty quick. It is do-able but not without risks