# Three hour connection in Frankfurt

Tags: air-travel, short-connections

I am thinking on a trip from Málaga to Holguín. The fastest and cheapest way seems with Lufthansa and Condor, with a connection in Frankfurt (see [this](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/178012/why-does-agp-fra-hog-not-appear-in-flight-searches) question for details). This itinerary **cannot** be sold as a single ticket. For the departing flight, I am resigned to an overnight layover, but this (sort of) guarantees the connection.

The returning flight is HOG-FRA (Condor 2207, 29 Jan) with expected arrival at 9:45. Then the only direct departure seems to be FRA-AGP (Lufthansa 1149, 30 Jan) scheduled at 12:50

Is three hours enough to make this connection?

Some data:

- Schengen citizen
- International flight (origin Cuba) - intra-Schengen flight
- Checked-in luggage
- Separate tickets
- (Even if single ticket were possible, it looks like check-in again is [necessary](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/151992/will-condor-through-check-baggage-onto-lufthansa-flights-on-separate-tickets))

So, in summary: go down the plane, passport control, pick up luggage, customs, probably walking to a different terminal, check-in, security, go to gate... in three hours (if there is no delay)

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: If you can get this as a connecting ticket you should not normally need to check-in again in FRA. I have just returned to UK from Holguin via Frankfurt. The HOG-FRA flight departed about 1.5hrs late IIRC but made up time on the way so actually landed about 30mins late. The FRA-MAN leg did not require me to check in again, I just had to clear airside Security.

Comment: I have also done this on separate tickets, it is do-able if there are no significant problems along the way. It helps if you are familiar with FRA airport. And of course you need to be prepared for extra costs if you don’t make your connection (possibly travel insurance covering you for a delay might be an option)

Comment: @Traveller What is a "connecting ticket"? Is it something different from a single ticket? Condor does not sell this particular itinerary as a single ticket despite the agreement with LH

Comment: AFAIK (booking from UK) Condor sells a limited number of connecting tickets (ie one PNR, bags checked through, airside transit).  It could be that they just don’t offer connecting flights on the route you want, or there are none of these seats available for your date, it is relatively short notice and a popular time of year.

Comment: Presumably you have explored routing via another European city like Amsterdam which I believe has direct flights from Holguin?

Comment: @mdewey If you are aware of any such flight to Holguin please let me know. I could not find any **direct** flight (a connection in Havana, for instance, would be much more complicated, I have been told).

Comment: @mdewey There are no direct flights from Amsterdam to Holguin AFAIK, KLM flies to Havana

Comment: @Miguel You could look at flying via one of the Canadian airports, or maybe via Dominican Republic. The latter has never worked for me though

Answer (score 2):

Connections are never guaranteed, so it comes down to a risk assessment.

If all goes reasonably well, your chances of making it are quite good especially if you have a biometric passport. The last few times I arrived in Frankfurt immigration and customs were basically non-events. They might look a little more diligently at suitcases from Cuba, but that's hard to tell.

If they loose a bag or there is a significant delay in your arriving flight, than you may miss it.

IMO there is 90+% chance of making the connection, but it's hard to predict with any certainty.

Comment: Good point about the passport. Last time I transferred at a German airport they looked at my Spanish ID card as if I had shown a bomb :)

Comment: Update, just in case you wish to add it to the answer: I made it but it was extremely tight and stressful. The flight from Cuba had a 90 minute delay, but the unexpected part was baggage claim (30+ minutes). It looks like large baggage delays are common in FRA. One of us went to the check-in counter and asked the staff to extend the close time as much as possible, while the other waited for the baggage. Then he arrived running in the last second. With only cabin luggage it would have been easy, since passport control, customs and security took few seconds.